# Bash: How can I prefix my openSSL encrypted file with the IV?

Tags: bash, shell, encryption, openssl

When encrypting a file, using a known IV and key, how can I prefix the result file with the iv in plain text?
I don't want to have another file lying around, and usually when I encrypt things, I just prefix the iv in front of the encrypted file.

When I run

```
iv=$(openssl rand -hex 16)
openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -K <key> -iv $iv -in text.txt -out text.enc
```

my input text file was 779 Bytes, my output is 784 bytes. I need it to have the iv in plain text at it's prefix so that it's a total of 800 bytes.

Comment: I guess that this is not different from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/233104) although it doesn't have any answers either that do not use intermediate files, so there's that. Do note that shell programming is, well, not the same thing as complete programming. Using `perl` or a programming language (for OpenSSL, C would be the prime candidate) makes sense here.

Comment: See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64736/combine-the-output-of-two-commands-in-bash). Thus `{ echo -n $iv; openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -K <key> -iv $iv -in text.txt; } > text.enc` might be what you want.

Comment: Thank you @PresidentJamesK.Polk , I tried something similar, but I didn't know about `-n`. I just have to get `echo -n $iv` down to 16 Bytes and not 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @PresidentJamesK.Polk 's comment, I figured it out:

```
{ echo $iv | xxd -r -p; openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -K <key> -iv $iv -in text.txt; } > text.enc
```

The `xxd -r -p` seemed t correctly convert to Bytes and wrapping in `{}` got the final file to the required 800 Bytes (16 Bytes of hex string = 32 hex chars => Size(encoded) + 16)